# End to End Traceability in Azure DevOps for any work item until deployment

Tags: azure, azure-devops, workitem

in azure DevOps, if changes in the form of the work item are committed. That WI further builds and deployed... So can I get a tabular data as when it was build/rebuild and deployed in any of which environment and what is the current status of that WI?

Comment: Sorry not totally get your point. Do you mean that you want to get the data from work item after deployment/build?  Can you explain your requirements in detail? Or you can share what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

You will be able to get this info as below:

- While commiting the code changes you should associate the work item
- After commiting the CI Build will trigger. Post that in that work item, there will be link reference to the Build
- And when this build is deployed to any of the release environments, it will be displayed under. You can check this new feature introduced in Azure DevOps [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/work-items/work-item-deployments-control?view=azure-devops)

But if you want all this information in a table, in one single view. You have to use Azure DevOps REST APIs to build a customer report to get all the data in one place.